# How can I install a washing machine in the kitchen?

Tags: plumbing, washing-machine, drain-waste-vent

i am looking to install  only a washing machine (no drier)  in my condo under the counter in the kitchen. my brother tried to install it for me but some plumbers advised him not to just hook it up because of the plumbing system 2 inch 1 and 1/2 inch... in any way i understand the concern but i just want to know if it is possible if i hire a professional plumber can they be able to change the whole plumbing system to accommodate the washer in the kitchen ? if it is easy to do it my brother can do it but how? i appreciate any comment.

Comment: Washing machines generally need to empty into an open drain, not directly into a closed pipe.  I think this to avoid the high volume/pressure pulling the water out of the trap, but wait for a response from a more serious plumber.

Comment: Can you clarify the information about the diameters/inches?

Comment: Yes it can be done and I've seen it done.  I think the pipe issue may be to do with the drain.  Because washing machines empty out quickly and they need to have the drain capacity to prevent back flow and a leak on your floor

Comment: It used to be common for small portable washing machines and dishwashers to just be set up to empty into a large sink. That has obvious advantages for folks living in apartments where they can't alter the plumbing. It may not make sense for this case, of course.

Answer (score 1):

A friend of mine recently purchased a portable washer that hooks up to the sink. Are you sure this won't work for you, instead? It would avoid having to tear out cabinets, etc. to put an appliance never designed to be put in a kitchen, where it shouldn't be. It might be somewhat in the way when in use, but avoids taking up cabinet space when not in use, as it can be wheeled out into another room when not needed.

She purchased the kit that made a small washer portable (wheels, drain line that goes into the sink, and the hoses that connect to the faucet.)

Also, these units are typically of very small capacity, which might be a consideration. Is there no other area where a compact washer/dryer unit for condos would fit?

Answer (score 0):

over in the UK we have a product called Saniflo (it's probable that there are numerous similar products in the US) which would sort that problem out very easily.

Answer (score 0):

Can it be done - yes. Can it be done in your condo's kitchen - not too clear from your description, though if you are willing to have pipes replaced (if needed) to get an adequately sized drain pipe, probably yes. Depending on the exact layout of your plumbing and access (or lack of access) to it, that could be quite expensive - or not. Your current description of pipe sizes is unclear, to say the least - please improve it to get a better answer.

One issue with an undercounter install is the height of the drain entrance - many (most top-loaders) washers need that to be somewhat higher than the machine itself, so it might be above the counter level - but this may not apply to your specific clothes washer (presumably a front-loader if going under the counter.) Check the clothes-washer manual on that, it should also have details about the drain requirements. If you have not purchased one yet, you could shop with "what you can manage easily" in mind so as to make the machine fit the plumbing you have rather than vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

They make washer/dryer combo's that are designed for under counter installs.  They are about the size of a dishwasher and are vent-less (they condense the damp air and use the drain).  I'm not sure how they connect the drain as I have never personally seen one.